# How to only download specific files from remote server instead of whole project?

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

I created a new project from remote sources and entered my servers data. PhpStorm instantly began to download the whole Magento project, even though I only need specific files for development, e.g. I don't need all the images or cache folders for my purpose. Now it takes 4-5 hours to download the whole project.

In NetBeans you can choose which folders you want to download to your machine, is this also possible in PhpStorm?

Comment: Yes it's possible. You should have marked such unwanted folders as "Excluded from Download" -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/create-new-project-choose-remote-path.html . Other than that -- just create empty local project and then configure the rest manually (deployment etc); once done --- Browse Remote Host and download only folders you need. Another way -- download all needed files locally first using you preferred program (e.g. FileZilla)  and then just point to the project root folder in "Open" dialog -- it will create new projects from those files.

Comment: Ohh I see, I totally missed this somehow. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

You should have marked such unwanted folders as "Excluded from Download" -- [image]

See [official help page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/create-new-project-choose-remote-path.html) for appropriate wizard step.

---

Other ways of creating a project:

- Just create empty local project and then configure the rest manually (deployment etc); once done use "Browse Remote Host" and download folders/files you need.
- Another way -- download all needed files locally first using you preferred program (e.g. FileZilla) and then just point to the project root folder in "Open" dialog -- IDE will create new project from those files.